# Доступ к PostgreSQL из Docker контейнера

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, postgresql9.5

Я пытаюсь соединиться с БД PostgreSQL (9.5.7) из контейнера docker (у него ip своей сети 172.19...). Контейнер запущен на том же хосте что и БД.
Но получаю ошибку в psql контейнера

> Is the server running on host "ip" and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

где ip различные вариции из: 127.0.0.1, localhost или ip адрес хоста.
Все хорошо если в pg_hba.conf прописать

> host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0          md5

а в postgresql.conf

> listen_addresses="*"

Но для продашина не хочется держать такую конфигурацию.
Прошу помочь разобраться, как настроить Postgresql, чтобы иметь возможность подключаться к нему из контейнера со своим ip (не обязательно будет сеть 172.19..., для другого контейнера может быть другая)

Comment: Насколько понимаю, вы можете постгре заставить слушать все входящие подключения, но с помощью pg_hba.conf зарезать все, кроме 127.0.0.0/8 и какого-нибудь 172.0.0.0/24. Альтернативно - заставить постгре слушать unix socket и пробросить его в контейнер.

Comment: как вариант попробовать БД тоже перенести в контейнер Docker

Answer (score 1):

> listen_addresses="*"

Так и оставил.

Включил `ufw`.

```
5432/tcp on docker_gwbridge ALLOW Anywhere
5432/tcp (v6) on docker_gwbridge ALLOW Anywhere (v6)
```

Теперь PostgreSQL доступен только для `docker_gwbridge` извне.

Локально на любом интерфейсе.